# Angular Bootstrap 4 modal fluid content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

i am trying to fit a media list inside a bootstrap `card`. However, when i try to zoom-in the browser, the media list `<ul/>` keeps on going out the `modal-body` which also goes out of bootstrap `card`.

How do i do fit he media list `<ul/>` within the `card` which also does not go out of `modal-body`. basically i want to keep it within the boundaries of the modal body either when zooming-in or just 100% view. Please see sample image below.

Also, here is my [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpy8uh)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This part of code

```
<div class="modal-body px-0 py-0" style="height:90vh">..
```

Why do you need static height? I see, there is a difference between scroll the modal element down or scroll down inside the modal element. But the physical result is the same - customer get the information. BS modal elements start to act weird with static height. Just try not to use it or can try to add

```
.modal-body .row {overflow-y: auto;}
```

and see what happens. But the main issue is static height, like style="height:90vh" or class="h-100".

Comment: I see, i just wanted it to have a fix height because the photos on the left side does not have a fixed height. so i want to have a fixed height container. That is why i put a static height on the modal. 

So in order to have a fixed height modal, i should declare the static height on the contents of the modal rather than the modal itself? is it correct?

Comment: I think, the idea of a fixed-height modal is overrated. As I said earlier, bootstrap modal works incorrect with fixed height. more problem begins on mobile adaptation. You can although try using image not with tag <img.. but like <div style="background-image:(..)". This way you can manipulate image like you want. If this information not enough - I can fix you example.

Comment: can't picture out what you mean, an example would be very much appreciated.